# Hibernate Sessions not thread safe

Tags: hibernate

why hibernate session is not thread safe?
Hibernate sessions are single threaded.
single thread objects are by default thread safe.
but how hibernate session is not thread safe can anybody explain this

Answer (score 2):

Threadsafe means that you can safely use the object from multiple threads at the same time. You should not be doing this with Hibernate sessions. They are not threadsafe and you'd get errors.

> Hibernate sessions are single threaded.

What do you mean by that?

The session is only "single threaded" if you don't share it between multiple threads (which would be bad, but you could write code that does it).